# How to store a 16-bit per channel image in a file?

Tags: c++, image, file, c++11

I have been developing an C++ application that downloads a grayscale 16bit per pixel image from a camera.

Since most libraries that I know don't support 16bit per pixel, for storing images on a file, I would like to discover which are the image formats and libraries for loading and storing images with this feature.

For that, I would like to have a code snippet for writing a 16-bit image to a file.

Comment: The question has been edited and it is compliant with stackoverflow requirements.
Please, allow this content to live and help improve community knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely candidates for supporting 16-bit greyscale images are:

- NetPBM's [PGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) format - this is a very simple to read and write format, and doesn't really need a library. It doesn't support much meta-data, other than a size though. It is not very space-efficient as it doesn't support compression but hey, storage is cheap!
- PNG format - this is a very popular, and flexible and efficient format and is understood by all software packages.
- TIFF format - very popular and very flexible format, understood by nearly all applications and very interchangeable amongst platforms and applications. Good also for DeepZoom, for multi-image/multi-layer files and also for storing metadata.

All the above are readily supported by [CImg](http://cimg.eu) which is a superb, cross-platform, modern C++ toolkit (without the complexity of **OpenCV**), and also **ImageMagick** which works across all platforms and all formats. There is also `libtiff` and `libpng` for reading and writing these formats. All the libraries mentioned above are happy with 16-bit images. If you need highest speed of processing at all costs, you pretty much need OpenCV.

My experience generally says that Python support for 16-bit images is somewhat difficult, if you are heading down that route.

---

If you plan to use **ImageMagick**, be sure to install the `Q16` version with 16-bit quantisation. You will then be able to generate sample 16-bit images for your algorithms like this at the command-line:

```
# Create 16-bit black-to-white gradient image as PNG
magick -size 300x200 gradient: -depth 16 gradient.png

# Create solid black, 16-bit PGM in P5/binary mode
magick -size 300x200 xc:black black.pgm

# Create solid, dark-grey 16-bit PGM, in P2/ASCII mode
magick -size 300x200 xc:gray10 -compress none darkgrey.pgm

# Create 16-bit, black to white gradient as TIF
magick -size 300x200 gradient: -depth 16 gradient.tif
```

[image]

```
# Create 16-bit TIF filled with random greys
magick -size 300x200 -colorspace gray xc:gray +noise random random.tif
```

[image]

```
# Create some shapes as 16-bit PGM
magick -size 300x200 xc:black                   \
   -fill white  -draw "rectangle 20,10 120,110" \
   -fill gray40 -draw "circle 180,100 180,130"  shapes.pgm
```

[image]

You will also be able to convert between all the formats I have mentioned:

```
# Convert TIF to PGM
magick input.tif output.pgm

# Convert PNG to TIF
magick input.png output.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

TIFF file format has support for storing images in 16-bit per pixel, and applications such as **ImageJ** are capable of reading these files.

I have developed a sample application that reads a raw buffer from a file and stores this buffer in TIFF format, using *libtiff*.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <tiffio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("input.data", "rb");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(fsize);
    fread(buffer, fsize, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    int imgWidth = 640;
    int imgHeight = 512;

    TIFF* tiff = TIFFOpen("output.tif", "w");

    TIFFSetField(tiff, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, imgWidth);
    TIFFSetField(tiff, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, imgHeight);
    TIFFSetField(tiff, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
    TIFFSetField(tiff, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 16);

    for(int i = 0; i < imgHeight; i++)
    {
        TIFFWriteScanline(tiff, &buffer[i*imgWidth*2], i);
    }

    TIFFClose(tiff);

    return 0;
}
```

To compile this on Linux:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -ltiff
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual [PGM format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) supports 16 bit grayscale images, and it's so trivial that using a library to parse and dump it is mostly superfluous - `scanf` and `fread` are more than enough.